# Why is this Blazor embedded component not updating correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

Given `MainView.razor`, which contains code which needs to be reused, the reusable code is moved into `NewComponent.razor`. `NewComponent` needs a single parameter, `Route route` in the example below. The parameter is passed via parameter specification.

`MainView.razor`

```
<NewComponent route="@route" />
```

`NewComponent.razor` is augmented so that any changes are noted on the console.

`NewComponent.razor`

```
@code
{
    Route _route;
    [Parameter]
    public Route route
    {
        get { return _route; }
        set
        {
            Console.WriteLine("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX Route = " + value.Name);
            _route = value;
        }
    }

    protected override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYZZ");
        return base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    }
}
```

However, no console output is ever specified. Updating `Resource.razor`

```
Route _route;
[Parameter]
public Route route
{
    get { return _route; }
    set
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Route changing to = " + value.Name);
        _route = value;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Outputs that the route is changing but the console output for NewComponent never happens. Why is NewComponent not updating?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that NewComponent was initially compiled in the `/Pages` directory and then moved to the `/Components` directory in the project. Hovering over `<NewComponent route="@route" />` demonstrates that the `.Pages` namespace is used even though there is no file stored there. A clean rebuild corrects this issue.